# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys..........)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to loop through the array of objects. Value of this.state.saveFriendTag or this.props.userTags on console is:

[image: Array of objects I am trying to loop through]

State in constructor is:
saveFriendTag: this.props.userTags? this.props.userTags: [],

Code is:

```
if(this.props.cardData){
  if (this.state.saveFriendTag.length == 1) {
    taggedFriendsBlue =  this.state.saveFriendTag.map((item, index) => {
      console.log(item,"item");
      return (
        <span className="displayedName blue" key={index}>{item.firstname}</span>
      )
    })
  }
```

[image: Error On Console]

This is in return and taggedFriendsBlue  is defined in render:

```
 <div className="pCard_contentContainer ">
     <textarea id="pcardTextarea" type="text" placeholder="Write Description here..." value={this.state.Description} onChange={this.textareaExpansion.bind(this)}></textarea>
       <If test={this.state.tagDone == true || this.state.saveFriendTag.length>0}>
       <div className="displayNames disp_inliFl">
         <span className="pcard_WithOne">-With</span>
           <div className="disp_inliFl">
               {taggedFriendsBlue}
           </div>
       </div>
    </If>
  </div>
```

Can anybody tell the reason for this console error? How to correct it?

Comment: Can you show full render method of the component?

Comment: If the collection you are attempting to iterate is an Array, you don't have to specify `Object.keys`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you are using `Object.keys` on an array. You can remove that and just use `.map` directly.

Additionally, you need to specify a key for the `span`.

`<span key={item.id} ... />`

```js
const array = [
  {
    firstName: "test",
    lastName: "test2"
  }
];

console.log(Object.keys(array));
```

As you can see from the code snippet, using `Object.keys` on an array will result in the index being passed on each iteration of the map function, instead of the object as you intend.

Comment: @YogeshDevgun what are you asking?

Comment: @YogeshDevgun don't forget to include the `key` property on the div.

Comment: Also, in the snippet you just commented, `item` is an object. So you should be doing something like `item.firstName` or something, to get the value, not using the object by itself.

Comment: @Mathew Sorry for last post! `taggedFriendsBlue =  this.state.saveFriendTag.map((item, index) => {
          console.log(item,"item");
          return (
            <span className="displayedName blue" key={index}>{item.firstname}</span>
          )
        })` this is what I an using now. I have added key to span also and removed Object.Keys directly mapping the array. but same error on console is there

Comment: Does that work for you or are you still seeing the error?

Comment: Can you update your post to include the full render function? The full component

Comment: @mathew Done Updating.. whole component is 1000 line code

Comment: @YogeshDevgun can you add the state definition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151098/discussion-between-yogesh-devgun-and-matthew).

Comment: This is my current code: `if (this.state.saveFriendTag.length == 1) {
        taggedFriendsBlue =  this.state.saveFriendTag.map((item, index) => {
          console.log(index,"Item", item.firstname,"item", item);
          return (
            <span className="displayedName blue" key={index}>{item.firstname} </span>
          )
        })
      } ` Values on console are getting printed but span tag throws same error.